# Getting error accessing data value in paypal function using vue and javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass value for total to paypal function but getting error. Here is my code. Check this line **amount: { total: this.total, currency: 'USD' }**

```
<template>
.........
</template>

<script>
export default{
  data(){
    return{
      total:0 //
    }
  },
  methods:{
        createPaypalButton(){
      paypal.Button.render({
          env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production
          // PayPal Client IDs - replace with your own
          // Create a PayPal app: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/create
          client: {
              sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
              production: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
          },
          // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
          commit: true,
          // payment() is called when the button is clicked
          payment: function(data, actions) {
              // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
              return actions.payment.create({
                  payment: {
                      transactions: [
                          {
                              amount: { total: this.total, currency: 'USD' } **//in above line this.total gives error.**
                          }
                      ]
                  }
              });
          },
          // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
          onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
              // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
              return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                  window.alert('Payment Complete!');
              });
          }

      }, '#paypal-button-container');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Without knowing the API of `paypal.Button`, this is very probably because your `this` is not the Vue component. Can you try putting `var self = this` at the top of `createPaypalButton` and using `self.total` instead of `this.total` ?

Comment: @Botje, thanks that worked for me.